# Altering values within blocks in Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I have a block of code that adds an object to an array declared outside the block with the "__block" notation (it's an ivar). However, once the block is exited, the array contains no values. I know that it isn't trying to add empty strings to the array, because my console prints the strings correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

`addressOutputArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

```
for(CLLocation *location in locationOutputArray)
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
         {
             CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

             NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@", [topResult subThoroughfare],[topResult thoroughfare],[topResult locality], [topResult administrativeArea]];

             [addressOutputArray addObject:address];

             NSLog(@"%@",address);
         }

     }];

    [geocoder release];
}

NSLog(@"Address output array count: %d", [addressOutputArray count]);
```

The final log gives me a count of zero. Any help at all would be really appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `reverseGeocodeLocation` is asynchronous, and you're not waiting long enough before you try to print the length of your array?

Comment: it is async but the code is in the completionHandler. And Mason says that the logging of the string works. which means that the loaded result is there.

Comment: iOS 5 is under NDA. However, aroth is right.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `reverseGeocodeLocation` executes asynchronously, and you are not waiting for the calls to complete before logging the size of your output array.  You might have better luck with something like:

```
for(CLLocation *location in locationOutputArray)
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
         {
             CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

             NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@", [topResult subThoroughfare],[topResult thoroughfare],[topResult locality], [topResult administrativeArea]];

             [addressOutputArray addObject:address];

             NSLog(@"%@",address);
             NSLog(@"Address output array count is now: %d", [addressOutputArray count]);
         }

     }];

    [geocoder release];
}
```

In any case, you are doing everything correctly with your block in terms of how you are setting it up and using it to modify the state of your `addressOutputArray` ivar.  The only problem is that you were not waiting until all your blocks had finished executing before checking the result.

Comment: I'm a little concerned about the geocoder getting deallocated before the asynchronous operation completes, if performing that operation doesn't cause anything to retain it (maybe the runloop does, but it's still fishy to me).

Comment: Thank you so much. That response was super helpful. Except not I'm getting a SIGABRT when it tries to populate a UITableView's detailTextLabel (through cellForRowAtIndexPath) because I guess the request to fill the array hasn't been completed yet. Is there an obvious solution for this that I'm missing?

@Joe, is using an autorelease call at the initialization better?

Comment: @Mason - I would recommend adding a line to your block that invokes some callback method on your controller.  Then the controller can either defer trying to populate the `UITableView` until after it knows all the requests are complete, or (preferably) refresh the table on each callback, loading only those rows that you have data for in the array (so you'd need to update your code to return the current size of the array as the number of rows/sections in the table).

Comment: Thanks so much! I finally figured it out (kind of). I still don't really have an understanding of why these things are called asynchronously. Is there a way to customize the order in which the operations are called? (i.e. do not start this method until the address array has been completely populated)

Comment: Aroth's suggestion is just what I would recommend, possibly with an instance variable that counts how many geocoding requests are still pending. I think it's a real flaw in `CLGeocoder`'s API that you seem to have to create a separate object for each request. For maximum safety, I would store the `CLGeocoder`s which have not yet finished in an instance variable on the controller--a retained `NSSet`, probably--and have the completion handler remove them from that set. The crux of it is not release vs autorelease, but whether we can assume that the runloop will hold on to the geocoder.

Comment: As a side note: Since `CLGeocoder` is an iOS 5 API, why not use ARC? (And as for why the geocoding requests are asynchronous: they involve network traffic and have a variety of failure modes.)